# how to $_REQUEST in php h

Tags: php

I was doing gallery using SQL and PHP and encountered a problem. I have 3 .php files and on each one I need to get different kind of information from the same SQL database according to what I have chosen on the previous page.

Comment: No idea what you are asking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make this page in your root directory named `connection.php` which will have this only code

```
<?php
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
?>
```

If you are using local wamp server then `"user"="root"` and `"password"=""` and database is name of you database.

then to extract any data in a page you need this in that page

```
<?php
    require_once("../connection.php");
?>
```

then on that page you perform a query like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE tableName SET this='valueThis' WHERE id='{$id}'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```